# Can ACI ( Azure Container Instance ) in peered vnets communicate?

Tags: azure-container-instances

In vnet-a, subnet-a there is aci-a.

In vnet-b, subnet-b there is aci-b.

If the virtual networks are peered both ways, shouldn't the containers be able to ping each other?

In my case, they can't. I've followed these pages:

Creating ACI in subnet:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet

Peering:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the virtual networks are peered both ways, shouldn't the containers
>   be able to ping each other?

Actually, No. And the Virtual network deployment is just the preview version. It seems that your containers just can communicate securely with other resources in the same virtual network.

Through the test, container groups just can communicate with each other in the same Subnet or different Subnets in the same VNet. Maybe they can communicate between different VNets with peering later in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Currently VNET regional and global peering are not supported by ACI. We're working on this and regional peering should be enabled in the next few months, with global peering later down the road. Your scenario you describe should be supported by regional peering if both of your VNETs reside within the same Azure region.

Check back with us at aka.ms/aci/updates for the latest news and leave us feedback at aka.ms/aci/feedback if peering is a requirement for you!

Thanks for using our service!